# Filter Array object by comparing with other Array object

Tags: jquery, arrays

Am having 2 array one with below format

```
var obj1 = [{
    "Name": "Test1",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "Name": "Test2",
    "id": 4
}];
```

and the other one

```
var obj2 = [{
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "Name": "Test3",
    "id": 4
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 5
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 6
}];
```

I need to compare obj1 and obj2 and remove the items from obj2 which are not in obj1 based on Id. And always in obj2 my id 1 and 2 should not get deleted.

My final o/p should be

```
var output = [{
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 5
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 6
}]
```

So i have retained 1 & 2 from obj 2 and removed item 5&6 which are not listed is obj1 in the same order.

I have tried with for looping and using slice and ended up no where. some help would be great

Thanks

Comment: @Tushar i will update question i had tried with for loop onside another for and comparing. but thought some other easy way would exist

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.some` method over `Array.prototype.filter` method to get the arrays compared and adjusted.

Here is a function:

```
function compareArrays() {

        //use filter method to create a new array after iteration of obj2
        return obj2.filter(function (obj2Item) {

            //Use some method to iterate obj1
            return obj1.some(function (obj1Item) {

                //Exclude desired items here 
                return (obj1Item.id === obj2Item.id) || (obj2Item.id === 1) || (obj2Item.id === 2);
            });

        });   

    };
```

See how these methods work.

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function to filter items based on a condition and indexOf to check the item exist condition.

```
var obj1 = [{
    "Name": "Test1",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "Name": "Test2",
    "id": 4
}];

var obj2 = [{
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "Name": "Test3",
    "id": 4
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 5
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 6
}];

var filterObject = $.map(obj2, function (v){
    if (v.id == 1 || v.id == 2) {
        return v;
    }
    else {
        var ids2 = $.map(obj1, function (vId){
            return vId.id;
        });

        if (ids2.indexOf(v.id) != -1) {
            return v;
        }
    }
});
```